# How do I order the elements in a group by linq query, and pick the first?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a set of data that contains a type, a date, and a value.

I want to group by the type, and for each set of values in each group I want to pick the one with the newest date.

Here is some code that works and gives the correct result, but I want to do it all in one linq query rather than in the iteration. Any ideas how I can achieve the same result as this with purely a linq query...?

```
var mydata = new List<Item> {
    new Item { Type = "A", Date = DateTime.Parse("2016/08/11"), Value = 1 },
    new Item { Type = "A", Date = DateTime.Parse("2016/08/12"), Value = 2 },
    new Item { Type = "B", Date = DateTime.Parse("2016/08/20"), Value = 3 },
    new Item { Type = "A", Date = DateTime.Parse("2016/08/09"), Value = 4 },
    new Item { Type = "A", Date = DateTime.Parse("2016/08/08"), Value = 5 },
    new Item { Type = "C", Date = DateTime.Parse("2016/08/17"), Value = 6 },
    new Item { Type = "B", Date = DateTime.Parse("2016/08/30"), Value = 7 },
    new Item { Type = "B", Date = DateTime.Parse("2016/08/18"), Value = 8 },
};

var data = mydata.GroupBy(_ => _.Type);

foreach (var thing in data) {

    #region 
            
    // How can I remove this section and make it part of the group by query above... ?          
    var subset = thing.OrderByDescending(_ => _.Date);
    var top = subset.First();
    
    #endregion
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{thing.Key} {top.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} {top.Value}");
}
```

Where `Item` is defined as:

```
public class Item {     
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}     
}
```

Expected output:

```
A 2016-08-12 2
B 2016-08-30 7
C 2016-08-17 6
```

Comment: Using the underscore as parameter name for a parameter you do actually use is very unusual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `select` to get the `FirstOrDefault` (or `First` - because of the grouping you won't get a null) ordered descending:

```
var data = mydata.GroupBy(item => item.Type)
                 .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                 .FirstOrDefault())
                 .ToList();
```

Or `SelectMany` together with `Take(1)`

```
var data = mydata.GroupBy(item => item.Type)
                 .SelectMany(group => group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                 .Take(1))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: missing semicolons

Comment: @Ehsan - fixed it now

Comment: All the answers are good and it's hard to pick one... but you gave an alternative with the SelectMany... so I'm going with this one. Thanks!

Comment: @BG100 - ha-ha thanks :) much appreciated - what I like about the idea with the `select many` and `take` is that if you need top X items that's the way - so just to have this idea passed on (even if it isn't for this specific case )

Comment: @GiladGreen your first code won't work, `FirstOrDetault()` won't work here

Comment: @Mostafiz - Why not?

Comment: @BG100 try the first one, in my case its isn't working

Comment: @Mostafiz - there was a typo of t instead of f

Comment: plus 1 for also referencing the documentation site.

Answer (score 2):

You can `Select` the first element of the ordered groups:

```
var topItems = mydata.GroupBy(item => item.Type)
                     .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(item => item.Date).First())
                     .ToList();
```

`topItems` is now a `List<Item>` containing only the top items per `Type`.

---

You may also retrieve it as `Dictionary<string,Item>` mapping the `Type` strings to the top `Item` for that `Type`:

```
var topItems = mydata.GroupBy(item => item.Type)
                     .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                              group => group.OrderByDescending(item => item.Date).First());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = mydata.GroupBy(
    item => item.Type,
    (type, items) => items.OrderByDescending(item => item.Date).First());

foreach (var item in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Type} {item.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} {item.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by type, for each group, order it by date descending and pick the first (newest).

```
mydata.GroupBy(i => i.Type).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).First());
```

Comment: There are already plenty of answers with the exact same code, why another one?  What makes yours different?

Comment: @sstan what makes those answers different from mine? I just saw a question and answered it properly

Comment: That's my question to you :)  If it's obvious that others have already answered the question the way you wanted to answer it, instead of posting a duplicate, upvote their answer.

Comment: @sstan I don't feel like explaining anything to you, sory, either you're guiding yourself by the "who got here first" principle or you're taking it personally with me.